# Figuring out duplicate dependency in war

Tags: java, maven-2

Could someone explain how do people get duplicate dependencies with different versions in their war? Maybe give some examples

I cannot understand for the live of me. Maven2 has dependency mediation for transitive dependencies

Say I have:

```
A
- B
- C

B
- E
```

Now in a project X, with war packaging I add A and B as dependency.

Because of the aforementioned dependency mediation, regardless of the version of B from project A, in the war I will see a single B jar with the declared version in X.

This because maven will use the version of the closest dependency to my project.

So, what am I missing here? How do people mess this up?
Looking forward to enlightenment

Comment: Just to be clear, the same thing happens with transitive dependencies further along the dependency tree. The closest one to the project is chosen

Comment: Dunno about WARs but I have seen people getting duplicated dependencies in EARs easily.

Answer (score 0):

For conflicting jars with same groupId and artifactId , maven takes the version coming from the dependency declared at last .

You can play with dependency order.
Just change the dependency order of A and B in project X .

**Scenario 1 : Here since 2.5 is added after 2.3 , 2.5 wil be packaged.**

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

**Scenario 2 : Here since 2.3 is added after 2.5 , 2.3 wil be packaged.**

```
<dependencies>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

**You can also try exclusion concept** [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: You want both the jars having different version to be packaged inside war?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, I do not understand how people run into this problem so I would like to try to reproduce it.
Also I am talking about transitive dependencies